# pip: yanked release is somehow accessible as default

Tags: python, pip, pypi

When I try to install a python package from pypi, somehow the yanked version is installed by default.

According to the history of the terminado package: https://pypi.org/project/terminado/#history version 0.13.0 is yanked, but when running the following

> h-ishida@0bbb747d2765:~$ pip install terminado==foo ERROR: Could not
> find a version that satisfies the requirement terminado==foo (from
> versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8,
> 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.13.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for terminado==foo

the top listed version is 0.13.0, which is yanked, and when try to install it without any version specification, 0.13.0 is installed.

Note that pip version is `9.0.1` for python2. The problem is that 0.13.0 is not compatible with python2 any longer, and thus the error occurred in installation.

What the cause of this bug? Is this `pip` or pypi's bug? or Did I made something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible you're using a buggy (<del>three-year-old!</del>five-year-old) version of Pip that doesn't know about yanked versions or can't figure out which versions of packages support Python 2 and Python 3, but also Python 2 has been end-of-life and out of support for 3 years, so you shouldn't be using it in the first place.

It looks like [`terminado==0.8.3`](https://pypi.org/project/terminado/0.8.3/) is the last version supporting Python 2 (based on the existence of a `py2.py3` wheel), so just explicitly install it if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks! But actually the mentioned method didn't work for my case. The problem is that  I want to use other package named `open3d` which depends on `terminado>=0.8.0`. I did first install `terminado==0.8.3` and then try to pip install `open3d==0.9.0` and then while `open3d` installation terminado version is updated to `0.13.0`, which causes the error.

Comment: You may be able to install them in the same `pip install` statement: `pip install open3d==0.9.0 terminado==0.8.3` (though this too could be a feature of a newer version of Pip). The other option is to install `open3d==0.9.0` first, then follow up by installing the correct version of terminado.

Comment: (As an aside: I can't reproduce this in a `python:2.7.10` Docker container with Pip 20.3.4; `pip install terminado` happily installs `0.8.3`, not the yanked version.)

Comment: Then do try install them in the same `pip` invocation so the incompatible 0.13.0 version isn't downloaded at all.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry my pip version was 9.0.1... (my pip3 version is 20.3.4 ...)

Comment: Oh, alright. You should be able to `python2 -m pip install -U 'pip<21.0'` (since 21.0 drops Python 2.7 compatibility) to make that pip as fresh as you can, then try again :)